# How can i use Findbugs 3.0.1 with Java 1.8 in Gradle 2.2.1 : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: gradle, findbugs, sonar-runner

```
here is the build run:

/opt/gradle-2.2.1/bin/gradle -noDB sonarRunner
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
:Backend:BenefitRequestProcessModels:test
:Backend:BenefitRequestProcessModels:generateCoberturaReport
Cobertura 2.1.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Report time: 125ms
Cobertura 2.1.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Report time: 141ms
:Backend:BenefitRequestProcessModels:performCoverageCheck SKIPPED
:Backend:BenefitRequestProcessModels:cobertura
:Backend:BenefitRequestProcessModels:sonarRunner
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_102 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Linux 2.6.32-504.1.3.el6.x86_64 amd64
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.3.1
13:04:00.824 INFO  - Install plugins
13:04:00.845 INFO  - Include plugins: buildbreaker
13:04:00.845 INFO  - Exclude plugins: devcockpit, buildstability, pdfreport, report, buildbreaker, scmactivity, views, jira
13:04:00.846 INFO  - Download sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.2.1.jar
13:04:00.986 INFO  - Download sonar-issues-report-plugin-1.3.jar
13:04:01.016 INFO  - Download sonar-groovy-plugin-1.0.1.jar
13:04:01.276 INFO  - Download sonar-l10n-en-plugin-4.3.1.jar
13:04:01.282 INFO  - Download sonar-toxicity-chart-plugin-0.2.jar
13:04:01.286 INFO  - Download sonar-widget-lab-plugin-1.5.jar
13:04:01.289 INFO  - Download sonar-maven-batch-plugin-4.3.1.jar
13:04:01.293 INFO  - Download sonar-surefire-plugin-2.2.1.jar
13:04:01.296 INFO  - Download sonar-cpd-plugin-4.3.1.jar
13:04:01.300 INFO  - Download sonar-ldap-plugin-1.4.jar
13:04:01.303 INFO  - Download sonar-fortify-plugin-1.1.jar
13:04:01.466 INFO  - Download sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.1.jar
13:04:01.500 INFO  - Download sonar-pmd-plugin-2.2.jar
13:04:01.654 INFO  - Download sonar-core-plugin-4.3.1.jar
13:04:01.663 INFO  - Download sonar-java-plugin-2.2.1.jar
13:04:01.672 INFO  - Download sonar-dbcleaner-plugin-4.3.1.jar
13:04:01.676 INFO  - Download sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.3.jar
13:04:01.679 INFO  - Download sonar-squid-java-plugin-2.2.1.jar
13:04:01.708 INFO  - Download sonar-design-plugin-4.3.1.jar
13:04:01.720 INFO  - Download sonar-email-notifications-plugin-4.3.1.jar
13:04:01.739 INFO  - Download sonar-build-breaker-plugin-1.1.jar
13:04:08.037 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
13:04:08.037 INFO  - Index files
13:04:08.312 INFO  - 59 files indexed
13:04:08.561 INFO  - Quality profile for java: U_Sonar_QualityProfile_With_StyleRules
13:04:08.690 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
13:04:08.816 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan...
13:04:08.823 INFO  - 6 source files to be analyzed
13:04:09.069 INFO  - 6/6 source files analyzed
13:04:09.075 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan done: 259 ms
13:04:09.077 INFO  - Java bytecode scan...
13:04:09.158 INFO  - Java bytecode scan done: 81 ms
13:04:09.158 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan...
13:04:09.159 INFO  - 53 source files to be analyzed
13:04:09.396 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan done: 238 ms
13:04:09.396 INFO  - 53/53 source files analyzed
13:04:09.411 INFO  - Package design analysis...
13:04:09.429 INFO  - Package design analysis done: 18 ms
13:04:09.470 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 780 ms
13:04:09.472 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor...
13:04:09.474 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor done: 2 ms
13:04:09.474 INFO  - Sensor CoberturaSensor...
13:04:09.474 INFO  - parsing /devops/SONAR-RUNNER/e-apps/Backend/BenefitRequestProcessModels/build/reports/cobertura/coverage.xml
13:04:09.573 INFO  - Sensor CoberturaSensor done: 99 ms
13:04:09.573 INFO  - Sensor PmdSensor...
13:04:09.575 INFO  - Execute PMD 5.1.1...
13:04:09.608 INFO  - Java version: 1.8
13:04:09.646 INFO  - PMD configuration: /devops/SONAR-RUNNER/elis-apps/Backend/BenefitRequestProcessModels/build/sonar/pmd.xml
13:04:09.997 INFO  - PMD configuration: /devops/SONAR-RUNNER/elis-apps/Backend/BenefitRequestProcessModels/build/sonar/pmd-unit-tests.xml
13:04:09.999 INFO  - Execute PMD 5.1.1 done: 424 ms
13:04:09.999 INFO  - Sensor PmdSensor done: 426 ms
13:04:09.999 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
13:04:10.018 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 19 ms
13:04:10.018 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
13:04:10.050 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 32 ms
13:04:10.051 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
13:04:10.056 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 5 ms
13:04:10.056 INFO  - Sensor FindbugsSensor...
13:04:10.058 INFO  - Execute Findbugs 2.0.3...
13:04:11.393 INFO  - Findbugs output report: /devops/SONAR-RUNNER/elis-apps/Backend/BenefitModels/build/sonar/findbugs-result.xml
The following errors occurred during analysis:
  Unable to get XClass for java/lang/StringBuilder
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5747
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:110)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:587)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:76)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.XFactory.getXClass(XFactory.java:652)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addInheritanceEdge(Subtypes2.java:1260)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addSupertypeEdges(Subtypes2.java:1233)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addClassAndGetClassVertex(Subtypes2.java:275)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addClass(Subtypes2.java:244)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.setAppClassList(AnalysisContext.java:941)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.setAppClassList(FindBugs2.java:997)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:225)
      At org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:201)
      At java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      At java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Unable to get XClass for java/lang/String
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5747
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:110)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:587)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:76)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.XFactory.getXClass(XFactory.java:652)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addInheritanceEdge(Subtypes2.java:1260)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addSupertypeEdges(Subtypes2.java:1233)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addClassAndGetClassVertex(Subtypes2.java:275)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addClass(Subtypes2.java:244)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.setAppClassList(AnalysisContext.java:941)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.setAppClassList(FindBugs2.java:997)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:225)
      At org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:201)
      At java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      At java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Unable to get XClass for java/util/Map$Entry
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5735
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:110)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:587)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:76)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.XFactory.getXClass(XFactory.java:652)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.setAppClassList(AnalysisContext.java:932)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.setAppClassList(FindBugs2.java:997)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:225)
      At org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:201)
      At java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      At java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Unable to get XClass for java/lang/CharSequence
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5747
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:110)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:587)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:76)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.XFactory.getXClass(XFactory.java:652)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addInheritanceEdge(Subtypes2.java:1260)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addSupertypeEdges(Subtypes2.java:1233)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addClassAndGetClassVertex(Subtypes2.java:275)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addClass(Subtypes2.java:244)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.setAppClassList(AnalysisContext.java:941)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.setAppClassList(FindBugs2.java:997)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:225)
      At org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:201)
      At java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      At java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Unable to get XClass for java/lang/Class
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 207
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(Unknown Source)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:110)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:587)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:76)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.XFactory.getXClass(XFactory.java:652)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addInheritanceEdge(Subtypes2.java:1260)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addSupertypeEdges(Subtypes2.java:1233)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addClassAndGetClassVertex(Subtypes2.java:275)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addClass(Subtypes2.java:244)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.setAppClassList(AnalysisContext.java:941)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.setAppClassList(FindBugs2.java:997)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:225)
      At org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:201)
      At java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      At java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Couldn't get class info for java/util/Map$Entry
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5735
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:110)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:587)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:76)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.XFactory.getXClass(XFactory.java:652)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.setAppClassList(AnalysisContext.java:932)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.setAppClassList(FindBugs2.java:997)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:225)
      At org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:201)
      At java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      At java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Couldn't get class info for java/lang/CharSequence
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5747
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:110)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:587)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:76)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.XFactory.getXClass(XFactory.java:652)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addInheritanceEdge(Subtypes2.java:1260)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addSupertypeEdges(Subtypes2.java:1233)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addClassAndGetClassVertex(Subtypes2.java:275)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addClass(Subtypes2.java:244)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.setAppClassList(AnalysisContext.java:941)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.setAppClassList(FindBugs2.java:997)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:225)
      At org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:201)
      At java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      At java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 13.265s
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
Final Memory: 18M/398M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Caused by: Can not execute Findbugs
ERROR: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 40705
ERROR: Caused by: 40705
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
:Backend:BenefitRequestProcessModels:sonarRunner FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Backend:BPM:sonarRunner'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Now i have tried : in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      maven {
         url "http://${project.ext.nexus}/nexus/content/groups/public"
       }
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'org.codehaus.sonar.runner:sonar-runner-dist:2.4'
      classpath 'com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs:3.0.1'
   }
}

subprojects {
   apply plugin: 'findbugs'
}
```

but could not find anyone having a successful build.gradle while running Java 1.8 with FindBugs 3.0.1 , in the gradle run you can clearly see that findbugs: Execute Findbugs 2.0.3... is being called , even though i have configured Findbugs 3.0.1 in build.gradle, so it must be wrong. it IS being resolved and the jar and pom are being downloaded from nexus just not getting called by gradle/sonarRunner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
13:04:10.058 INFO  - Execute Findbugs 2.0.3...
13:04:11.393 INFO  - Findbugs output report: /devops/SONAR-RUNNER/elis-apps/Backend/BenefitRequestProcessModels/build/sonar/findbugs-result.xml
```

You are most likely having a [really old version](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-findbugs#compatibility) of the Sonar-FindBugs plugin.
You can make the update by going to the update center.
http://YOUR_SONAR/updatecenter/installed

You may need to upgrade your Sonar to a later version also.

Comment: that is exactly what i did. Upgraded SonarQube to 5.6.1 LTS and that fixed the problem. Had to upgrade mysql as well. The upgrade guide is : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading